# Devise + Omniauth call action passthru on login Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

When I try to login with Facebook using Omniauth and Devise, `passthru` is called instead of `facebook`.  How do I pass in the `link_to`:

```
user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```

I've revised the code many times and tried to use this route:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } do
    get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
  end
```

and

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

But the error is same.  I have the action `facebook` in my `users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

Comment: Try out `alias_method :facebook, :passthru` at your `omniauth_callbacks` controller and pass `:facebook` to the `link_to`

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: No, whitout error but redirect to wrong action.

Comment: Same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248166/devise-omniauth-linkedin-error-not-found-authentication-passthru/27969579#27969579

Answer (score 3):

I just flailed with the exact same problem for hours, trying everything including doing the exact same process on a different branch with github oauth, which worked without a problem. What finally worked for me was changing the hash of arguments I was passing to config.omniauth in devise.rb after the app token and secret. It was `name: 'google'` that was doing it. Commented it out and it works:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 'ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
   {
    # name: 'google',
    scope: 'calendar, plus.login plus.me'
  }
```

Whether the id and secret are hard coded in has no effect. I didn't try it, but `:name` seems like it is used as an alias for the provider to use elsewhere in the code in place of `:google_oauth2`. Uncommenting it and changing it (redundantly) to `name: google_oauth2` works. I'm sure you've either solved it or moved on after a year but I hope this helps someone in the future.

onmiauth-google-oauth2 0.2.5

devise 3.4.0

rails 4.1.6

Answer (score 2):

In my case, we added the gem [omniauth-rails_csrf_protection](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection) but we were still trying to access the authorize endpoints using `GET` methods. Replacing those `GET` calls by `POST` requests (with the CSRF token) solved it.

Comment: Thank you, this was an issue for me too.

Comment: Have tried to update the Omniauth wiki to further reflect this issue: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Resolving-CVE-2015-9284

Answer (score 0):

The `passthru` route is an old relic from the omniauth past.

Just set your routes like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Comment: Generate the same error man, page blank whit prhase: 'Not found. Authentication passthru.'

Comment: Run `bundle update devise` and `bundle update omniauth` to update those gems, maybe you are using old versions. Also make sure that your `omniauth_callbacks_controller` is inside a folder called `users`.

Comment: What gems are you using? Are you including the `omniauth-facebook` gem?

Comment: Yes man, i include and run update in this also, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the configuration in devise.rb ?
you need to declare the provider in your (config/initializers/devise.rb) and require it

```
require "omniauth-facebook" 
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
```

You will need to restart the server also.