# Omniauth-facebook with Devise: "Missing passthru" errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have Devise authentication installed with no problems. Now I'm trying to add an option to log in with Facebook, using Omniauth-facebook.

I followed the instructions in [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview), but I'm getting errors about missing "Passthru" documentation, when visiting the url `localhost:3000/auth/facebook`.

Here's the first error I got:

```
Unknown action
The action 'passthru' could not be found for RegistrationsController
```

I tried a bandaid fix by just adding an empty "passthru" action to my controller:

```
def passthru
end
```

And that resolved that error, but I got a different one in return:

```
Template is missing
Missing template registrations/passthru, devise/registrations/passthru, devise/passthru, application/passthru with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/user/project/app/views" * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
```

I tried creating a "passthru.html.erb" in the stated folders, but that error remained. In any case, I think these errors are emblematic of a deeper problem.

Has anyone else run into this problem? All I could find on it was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513829/devise-omniauth-call-action-passthru-on-login-facebook), but none of the answers were helpful.

---

### **My code so far:**

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth'
```

**routes.rb**

devise_for :members, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', `omniauth_callbacks: 'registrations' }`

**member.rb**

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |member|
      member.email = auth.info.email
      member.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      member.title = auth.info.name
    end
  end
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
  def facebook
    @member = Member.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @member.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @member, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_member_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def passthru
  end
```

**initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "<app_id>", "<app_secret>"
```

Comment: Please describe what are you trying to achieve by `passthru` method?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri I don't want to do anything with it. The documentation doesn't say anything about passthru either. I think it's a relic from an old version of omniauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

**Update GemFile:**

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth'
```

**Goto rails_apps/yourapp/config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
   config.omniauth :facebook, "KEY", "SECRET"
 end
```

**Update the User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

         devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
    :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

     def self.from_omniauth(auth)
         where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
           user.provider = auth.provider
           user.uid = auth.uid
           user.email = auth.info.email
           user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
         end
     end
    end
```

**Goto : rails_apps/yourapp/config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
end
```

**Edit in View**

```
 <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Passthru is a relic from omniauth update your gems of devise omniauth and so on .
there is  a controller called omiauth_callback this is the one makes noizes ;P.(may help you trace the problem's source)

If you create a method in controller like so :

 `def passthru
 end`

You HAVE TO create a view with(even empty), or redirection :get inspired by ajax techniques to bypass html rendering .
Hope it send you on the way of problem solving .

try also theses routes :
```
user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)                sessions#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter|google/}

user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)                             sessions#(?-mix:facebook|twitter|google)
```

Comment: I just wrote "gem 'omniauth-facebook'" and that was about a week ago, so shouldn't I automatically have the latest version?

Comment: Humm depends  of Gemfile.lock  verify this file , and if necessary : gem upgrade gem_name .
Btw : def passthru;  render :layout => false ; end

Comment: ```
user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)                sessions#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter|google/}

   user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)                             sessions#(?-mix:facebook|twitter|google).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another controller for `Omniauth callback`

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    @user =  User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication 
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end


  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    super resource
  end

end
```

you need to reset your routes as

```
devise_for :members, :controllers => {:registrations => "members/registrations", :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

As i could remember you need not to use `:omniauth_providers => [:facebook]` in your `member.rb`

Now you can add a button in your `sign_up page` or instead include the below code in your `devise/shared/_links.html.erb`, because it will be available in your sign_in form also.

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "btn btn-default navbar-btn" %><br />
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

you also need to configure devise in initializers

In your `/config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "App ID", "App Secret", scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
```

Please go through this simplest tutorial for Sing_up with facebook [Link](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Integrating-Omniauth-with-Devise-in-Rails/19500/)

Comment: Are you sure I need a separate controller for Omniauth Callback? Why would it matter what controller it's in, as long as the route points to the correct one?

Comment: yes, you can do it in same controller but I usually do it in another controller, since It makes me clear that if I need to Include sign up with other social media like twitter, linkedIn, etc. then It will not make a mess in my registrations controller.

Comment: Yeah, so I think that other than that, I have the same code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .........

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_KEY"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"], { :scope => 'email, offline_access'}
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :members, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**app/models/member.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable


def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |member|
    member.email = auth.info.email
    member.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    member.title = auth.info.name
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def facebook
    p env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = "You are in..!!!"
      sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    #handle you logic here..
    #and delegate to super.
    super
  end
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: What's the difference in our code that you think might be causing my error? I can't find any meaningful difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is always on the button or the anchor, so use this

```
<%= link_to user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post do %>
login with facebook 
<% end %>
```